# Compressing video recording- file gets bigger!

Tags: compression, final-cut-pro, export

i have recorded a part of my screen (2624x1714, 8 hours, ca. 30 GB), then trim and cut in final cut pro. Now I want to compress it with Compressor. I set the output to HD 1080p but the file doesn't get smaller but bigger (36GB). Why? How should I proceed?

Thanks

L

Comment: What are the codecs, bit rates and frame rates of the original and the final videos? The end format will have half the pixels of the original, so if it's larger in file size its bit rate must be twice as high (simplifying).

Comment: okay i solved it by reducing the bit rate thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reducing the bitrate 
thank you